# ftp_put says file is uploaded successfully but there is no file found

Tags: php, ftp

So the ftp_put says the file is successfully uploaded, but if i check the server there is no file found, i have checked the chmod permissions and they are 777.
here is the message i get when i uploaded a file:

conectd as a9408563@server23.000webhost.com Het bestand is succesvol geupload(the file has been successfully uploaded). connection closed

and this is my code:

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "xxxx";
$ftp_username   = "xxx";
$ftp_password   =  "exxx";
$uploadedfile = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"];
$destination_path = "/public_html/files";
//setup of connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");
//login
if(@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
  {
  echo "conectd as $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
}
else {
  echo "could not connect as $ftp_username\n";
}
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
/*
$remote_file_path = "   /home/a9408563/public_html/files".$uploadedfile;
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $uploadedfile,
        FTP_BINARY);



ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/public_html/files/');
ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_path.$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"], $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY );
*/
if (ftp_nb_put($conn_id, $destination_path.$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"], $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY))
        {
            echo "Het bestand is succesvol geupload.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Het bestand is niet geupload.";
        }
        ftp_close($conn_id); 


echo "\n\nconnection closed";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ftp_nb_put` is more flexible than `ftp_put`, but also more complicated to check its result. A simple `if(ftp_nb_put())` call isn't enough.

Try using [`ftp_put()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) instead, or learn how to check for `ftp_nb_put`'s success [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-put.php):

```html
// Initiate the Upload
$ret = ftp_nb_put($my_connection, "test.remote", "test.local", FTP_BINARY);
while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA) {
   
   // Do whatever you want
   echo ".";

   // Continue uploading...
   $ret = ftp_nb_continue($my_connection);
}
if ($ret != FTP_FINISHED) {
   echo "There was an error uploading the file...";
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: well i tried using the ftp_put but i still get the same outcome, the file is not uploaded

Comment: Does it give you any error? If not, call first `ini_set('display_errors', 1) ; error_reporting(E_ALL); set_time_limit(0);`